# Calculating death rate from half life

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to use the information on half life of a substance to determine the death rate to be used in a differential equation. So, if the half life is 12, then should the death rate be `ln(2)/12`.

If it was mentioned the average life span is 12 hours, then would the death rate be 1/12.

For example, I want to find d, which is the death rate by using information on half life. 
${dS \over dt}=\mu-dS$